# HOw to add 1 day to the given input date (format: YYYY-MM-DD) using JCL Syncsort?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I want to add 1 day to the given input date. The input date is in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Can anybady please let me know how can I do this using Syncsort?

Ex:

Input date: 2011-10-31 (Format: YYYY-MM-DD)

Output date after add 1 day: 2011-11-01 (Format: YYYY-MM-DD)

Thank you,
Rajasekhar Jannu.

Answer (score 4):

You can use DATEADD in Syncsort MFX for z/OS 1.4 to add one day.

Example syntax (where p= field position and l= field length):

```
OUTREC FIELDS=(...DATEADD=(p,l,DT=(4MD-),+1,DAY),...)
```

Please contact zos_tech@syncsort.com if you require further assistance.

Brian Wood
Customer Service Representative
Syncsort Incorporated
201-930-8260

Comment: Hi Brain, I tried with your sortcard. I am getting 'WER268A  OUTREC STATEMENT  : SYNTAX ERROR'.Please find the Job log. SYNCSORT LICENSED FOR CPU SERIAL NUMBER C3132, MODEL 2817 711 
SYSIN :  SORT FIELDS=COPY  OUTREC FIELDS=(1:C'''',2:DATEADD(1,10,DT=(4MD-),+1,DAY),        
                      *                                       
                    12:C'''',                                 
                    68X)       
WER268A  OUTREC STATEMENT:SYNTAX ERROR. Please let me know what may be the problem???

Comment: If your SyncSort is prior to MFX for z/OS 1.4, then you won't have the DATEADD function.